# Custom Confirm Dialog

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, confirm

```
function deleteRecordDialog() {
    var returnThis;
    var numRecordss = recs.length;
    var html = ""
    /*html= html +'<div id="popupContainer" style="width:' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + '; display: block;">';
    html= html + '<div id="popupInner">';
    html= html + '<div id="popupFrame">';
    html= html + '<div class="margin15px dialog-messages">';*/
    html= html + '<table>';
    html= html + '<tr>';
    html= html + '<td class="warning-icon-cell"></td>';
    html= html + '<td style="padding-left: 5px;">';
    if (numAddresses == 1) {
        html = html + '<p>You have chosen to delete a contact.</p>';
    }
    else {
        html = html + '<p>You have chosen to delete ' + numAddresses + ' contact(s).</p>';
    }
    html= html + '<p>Are you sure you wish to proceed?</p>';
    html= html + '</td>';
    html= html + '</tr>';
    html = html + '</table>';
    if (numAddresses == 1) {
        html = html + '<div class="add-postage-submit-buttons"><input type="button" value="Yes, Delete Contact" style="width: 160px; onclick="returnThis=true; CloseDialog();"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="returnThis=false; CloseDialog();"/></div>';
    }
    else {
        html = html + '<div class="add-postage-submit-buttons"><input type="submit" value="Yes, Delete Contact(s)" style="width: 160px; onclick="returnThis=true; CloseDialog();"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="returnThis=false; CloseDialog();"/></div>';
    }
    html = html + '</div>';
    html = html + '</div>';
    html = html + '</div>';
    html = html + '</div>';
    OpenDialog(html, 350, 180, false, "Delete Contact")
    return returnThis;
}
```

Now usually I'd use JQuery and set modal to true to enable the false/true to be assigned but I don't have the luxury of jquery with this. Is there a way to use this custom dialog?

Is there a way to do the following without JQuery?

```
$("#dialogInfo").dialog({
    modal: true
});
```

Comment: Of course there is; you just need to write your own dialog methods.  After you've done it once, it's not that scary :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery-ui-dialog just runs a bunch of JavaScript code behind the scenes to give the appearance of a dialog box.

You can accomplish much of the same functionality using CSS.

I'm not going to tell you *exactly* what to do here, but I'll point you in the general direction.

For starters, you can create a `div` that will contain your dialog box content.  Give it id `dialog`.

Then, in CSS, give it `position:fixed` and `display:none` and `z-index:9999` along with the width and height you desire.  Knowing exactly what its size is, you can write JavaScript code to center it on the screen.  When you want to display the dialog, set its `display` property to `block`.   Also, be sure to give it a background color and a border. That will allow you to give part of your document the appearance of being like a dialog box.

If you want to have a 'mask' behind the dialog box so that the user can't click on anything else on the page, create another div with id `mask`.  Give it these CSS properties: `position:fixed`, `top:0px`, `left:0px`,`height:100%`, `width:100%`, `display:none`background-color:black`,`z-index:9998`,`opacity:0.8`.  When you want to display the dialog as modal, set this div's`display`property to`block` as well.

Finally, jQuery-ui-dialog also captures [Tab] key presses to keep the keyboard focus inside the modal dialog.  Feel free to do this as well, if you like.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Okay, so my OpenDialog function works. The pop up shows up it's just the fact that I'm not able to use JQuery to set it to modal. I'll have to do as described above and try to figure out a custom dialog script. Thanks for all the responses! :)

Comment: @DanielLangdon I'm looking into what you're saying. I have a mask and the pop up still. What, in your shove, is responsible for making it modal?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "modal" dialog in HTML or JavaScript.  jQuery-tabs-ui simply works some tricks with JavaScript to make a part of your page display as if it were a modal dialog box.  The idea is that you use the "mask" to cover up the page so that nothing else can be clicked while displaying the pop-up dialog on top of the mask.  Can you please describe your results in more detail and let us know what seems to be lacking?